# Changing what the command text-align:center is relative to in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a way to center(or align) text around one specific symbol or character. The text is user input that goes through a function in javascript that adds symbols.

I have text that is set to have a line break every 2 words. I have a dot in between these 2 words. I need to set each line to be centered but relative to the dot in-between them not relative to the conventional center. It doesn't have to be exactly center i just need to have each dot right below one another (with the surrounding text to move accordingly). The text is printing as a continuous string but it just has breaks to go to the next line: [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piCvZ.jpg).

I have the dots themselves set as a class inside the function. This is what the function looks like that puts them in: [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHsmP.jpg). I can edit just the dot in css but when I try to use css to center the dot it does nothing. I think because it doesn't know to move the text proportional to the dot when it is centered.

The text is original every time so the lengths of the words will not be consistent which is why I need it to be relative to the don not the middle of the length.

If more information is needed just ask i'm appreciative to be getting help:)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, it's text, copy paste it into your question. Just make sure to format it correctly with the code button `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the position of the dot using jquery position or offset method and move the text according to the dot's position.

- find the left offset value of the first dot and assign it to var x
- find the left offset value of the next nth dot and assign it to var a
- if( offtwo > offone ) move the line (offtwo - offone) units left
  else move the line (offone - offtwo) units right

link to example -
https://jsfiddle.net/TheTwin/8py75kc0/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var x = $('.dot').eq(0).offset().left;
for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementsByClassName('dot').length; i++) {

var a = $('.dot').eq(i).offset().left;
if (a > x) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('line')[i].style.left = '-' + (parseInt(a) - parseInt(x)) + 'px';
  console.log("moved -" + (parseInt(a) - parseInt(x)))
} else {
  document.getElementsByClassName('line')[i].style.left = (parseInt(x) - parseInt(a)) + 'px';
  console.log("moved " + (parseInt(x) - parseInt(a)))
}

console.log(i + '   ' + a);
}
})
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Make lines in HTML, like this:

```
<div><span>longer text</span><span>•</span><span>shrt txt</span></div>
<div><span>shrt txt</span><span>•</span><span>longer txt</span></div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
span {display: inline-block;}
span:nth-child(1) {width: calc(50% - 15px); text-align: right;}
span:nth-child(2) {width: 30px; text-align: center;}
span:nth-child(3) {width: calc(50% - 15px); text-align: left;}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZJQNX

Comment: how would i set it so it can have flexible text inputs so that the user can copy and paste their own text and have it arranged like that as many times as needed to get through the desired text

Comment: If you want the dots not in the middle, use a table (see the answer of Patrick Evans below).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to layout your words in columns manually through css just put your words into a `<table>` which will do that for you.

```
<tr>
  <td>word</td> <!--One word in a left column-->
  <td>.</td> <!--a dot in the center column-->
  <td>word</td> <!--other word in the right column-->
</tr>
```

Then just have the left columns aligned right, and the right columns aligned left (which is default)

```
table td:first-child {
  text-align:right;
}
table td:last-child {
  text-align:left;
}
```

Demo

```js
var input = 'European Space Agency hoping to spot the International Space Station';

input = input.match(/\w+\s\w+/g);

var table = document.createElement('table');
var body = table.createTBody();

input.forEach(text=>{
  let cols = text.split(' ');
  let row = body.insertRow();
  row.insertCell().innerText = cols[0];
  row.insertCell().innerText = '.';
  row.insertCell().innerText = cols[1];
});
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table td:first-child {
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: will this method work when the text can be an unlimited length of words and as a user input?

Comment: @t-engineer, Yes. As long as the format stays the same, ie word space word space etc, the regex I used will split it correctly. It will need updating if the format changes though.